# Ошибка запроса UPDATE SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, исключения, update

Требуется обновить строки таблицы с датой, соответствующей условию. При вызове метода для обновления вылезает исключение

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ".24": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE days_table SET expense = expense + 39.0 WHERE expdate = 2017.12.24
```

В чем проблема?

Код метода, в котором возникает исключение

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.etDate:
            DialogFragment dialogfragment = new DatePickerDialogClass();
            dialogfragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "Date Picker Dialog");
            break;
        case R.id.btnAdd:
            double dayExp;
            String day;
            String sCat ;
            String sComment;

            //Считывание данных из полей ввода
            dayExp = Double.parseDouble(etExp.getText().toString());
            day = etDate.getText().toString();
            sCat = tvSelCat.getText().toString();
            sComment = etComm.getText().toString();

            //Запись в БД
            boolean result = dbHelper.insertDayData(dayExp, sCat, day, sComment);
            if (result) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Расход успешно добавлен", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Ошибка! Расход не добавлен", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            //Обновляем таблицу с днями
            dbHelper.updateDaysData(dayExp, day);

            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
            break;
    }

}
```

Код метода для обновления записи

```
    public void updateDaysData(double dayExp, String day) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("UPDATE " + DAYS_TABLE_NAME + " SET " + DAYS_COL_2 + " = " + DAYS_COL_2 + " + " +
            dayExp + " WHERE " + DAYS_COL_4  + " = " + day);
}
```

Comment: Укажите свой код, пожалуйста.

Comment: Добавил код выше

Comment: Литерал даты (`WHERE expdate = 2017.12.24`) имеет неверный формат.

Comment: никогда не подставляйте значения непосредственно в текст. используйте подготавливаемые выражения и привязку данных. https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx  Но если вы все таки настаиваете и хотите создать приложение, которое будет подвержено sql-инъекциям, то просто посмотрите как даты задаются в SQLite, наверняка в каких нибудь кавычках, открытым текстом ни в одной БД даты не пишутся

Comment: Разобрался. В качестве разделителя в дате вместо точки должен стоять дефис.